How to replicate scroll behaviour using React Native Gesture Handler and React Natove Reanimated on SectionList?
I am building a React Native app and I wrapped the entry point of my app with TouchableWithoutFeedback component to detect press events outside other pressable/touchable components to hide active dropdown, dismiss the keyboard. This works well but it messed with ScrollView, FlatList and SectionList components' scroll functionality. I can't scroll these components, it sometimes detects the scroll event, sometimes doesn't, so it's completelty unreliable.
I don't know what's the best way to enable scrollable components to work reliably but I thought I can replicate the scroll functionality manually using React Native Gesture Handler and React Native Reanimated libraries. To do so, I set scrollEnabled={false} so scrollable component isn't scrollable by default. Then I used a GestureHandler and Gesture.Pan to do the manipulation but it reacts slowly to the move/change events' updates, even with useSharedValue hook to manage states/values. It also scrolls a lot more than my actual movement, so it's very sensitive.
Could you suggest a better way to ensure scrollable components are scrolled reliably or a way to reflect pan gesture to manually scroll?

I would recommend not doing this globally, instead, make a reusable container with a press event. You'll end up chasing edge cases for much longer than it's worth

@Abe sorry, I couldn't understand your idea. Could you tell about it more?
